# Adding a progress bar inside my method - wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a method that create an xml file. i need to create a progress bar that progress during the execution of the method.

this is my xaml code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <ProgressBar Name="progressbar" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"  IsIndeterminate="False" Margin="10,254,10,0"  />
</Grid>
```

this is my method inside the xaml.cs file

```
public void CreerEtudes(IEnumerable<CheckBox> SelectedAffaires, string SelectedPath, string NomEtude, string nomEtude, string compteur, string Path, string[] subdirectoryEntries)
{
    string[] affaireName = null;
    List<string> listepath = new List<string>();
    List<string> SchemasFolders = new List<string>();
    List<string> schemasDefaultFolder = new List<string>();

    Directory.CreateDirectory(SelectedPath + NomEtude);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(SelectedPath + NomEtude + "\\metadonnees");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(SelectedPath + NomEtude + "\\metadonnees\\tags");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(SelectedPath + NomEtude + "\\metadonnees\\notes");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(SelectedPath + NomEtude + "\\metadonnees\\schemas");
    File.Copy("C:\\N.O.E\\ref\\tags\\tags.xml", SelectedPath + NomEtude + "\\metadonnees\\tags\\tags.xml");

    XNamespace NspaceConf1 = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    XNamespace NspaceConf2 = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
    XDeclaration decConf = new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
    XElement Root = new XElement("EnvironmentXmlDto",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", NspaceConf1),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", NspaceConf2),
        new XAttribute("SousEnsembleTravail", "Affaire"));
    XDocument newConfig = new XDocument(Root);
    newConfig.Declaration = decConf;
    XElement Ecran = new XElement("Ecran", new XAttribute("Nom", "0"));
    XElement Cote = new XElement("Côté", new XAttribute("Nom", "Left"));
    Ecran.Add(Cote);
    Cote.Add(new XElement("Onglet", new XAttribute("Indice", "0"),
        new XAttribute("EstSelectionné", true),
        new XAttribute("Header", "Affaire")));
    Cote.Add(new XElement("Onglet", new XAttribute("Indice", "1"),
        new XAttribute("EstSelectionné", false),
        new XAttribute("Header", "Tags")));
    Cote.Add(new XElement("Onglet", new XAttribute("Indice", "2"),
        new XAttribute("EstSelectionné", false),
        new XAttribute("Header", "Etiquette")));
    Root.Add(Ecran);
    Root.Add(Preferences);
    newConfig.Save(SelectedPath + NomEtude + "\\metadonnees\\configuration.xml");


}
```

regards.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous as you've not declared what it is you actually want to report progress on. Is it per line of code that is executed within the method? Is it per file processed? etc... Progress is calculated by: `(tasksCompleted/totalTasks * 100)`.

Comment: it is by line code that is executed within the mehtod

Comment: So what is your issue then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the background worker's report progress method to get the current progress throughout the method. However, you will have to manual set the progress within the method. (This also requires you to use System.ComponentModel). You will have to add `bg1.ReportProgress(n) //n=0-100;` inbetween lines or by using a number in the method that starts from 0%(nothing) and becomes 100%(or maximum).

```cs
BackgroundWorker bg1 = new BackgroundWorker();
bg1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bg1.ProgressChanged +=  new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bg1_ProgressChanged);
bg1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg1_DoWork);

void bg1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e){
    float percent = e.ProgressPercentage()
}
void bg1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){
    for(int i = 0;i<100;i++){
        bg1.ReportProgress(i);
        Thread.Sleep(25);
    }
}
```

Comment: i added the repport progress between the blocks of my method and it work. thank you